# Regex with leading zeros

Tags: c#, regex

I need to match a filenames in the filelist with database rows by Regex.

- File names are numbers with leading zeros
- Database values are numbers without leading zeros

**Sample file list:**

```
0001.jpg
0002.bmp
...
0012.bmp
0013.bmp
0014.jpg
...
1012.jpg
...    
1015.jpg
...
```

I use C#. And I need to match each file name with each row in the database.

Comment: Where's the sample code you have been trying?

Comment: So you have a table with file names but the data does not match the file names exactly? What is your problem? Do you want it to match?

Comment: I use C#, but why does it matter? I need a regex match string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this regex

```
^0+\d+[.](jpg|bmp|jpeg|exe)
```

OR

```
^0+\d+[.]\S+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I need to look through all database rows and match each row with just one file. The above samples matches a lot of filenames.

Comment: @Murat the edit should work..it would match all filenames at the start of line

Comment: Anirudh, for example, I have a numeric field in our database, lets say 175, where I need to insert it into your regex expression to find a file 0175.*?

Comment: @Murat you can do it as `0+175[.](jpg|bmp|jpeg|exe)`

Comment: unfortunately this also finds 1175.jpg, 2175.jpg along with the 0175.jpg. But I need one-to-one connection between database rows and filenames.

Comment: @Murat ohh..how can i miss that use this: `\b0+175[.](jpg|bmp|jpeg|exe)`

Comment: Anirudh, thank you for your time! Your last answer works with me! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -2):

I'm somewhat reluctant to answer, but in order to match those file names (which is what I presume you are trying to do) you should try: `\d{4}\.(jpg|bmp)`

**EDIT:**

*Since you are so liberal with your -1's..*

Regex isn't really the correct technology to use to solve your coding problem, regex is used to find a string that matches a pattern.

The problem you appear to describe is that you have a poorly typed file system with unnecessarily added 0's and want to convert (for example) a `4` to `0004` and not care about what file extension you have.

The "best solution" to your problem is to fix the numbering system of your files or simply to add the leading 0's in c#, not to use a technology that is designed to do something completely different.

*Enjoy your -6.*

Comment: I need to match each file name with each row in the database. Your sample matches all the filenames in the list. For example, I need to match 56 in the database with 0056.jpg in the filelist, but not with 1056.jpg or 0156.bmp.

Comment: @Murat edited to fit your needs.